# How do I use nested lists properly in that context

Tags: python, function, printing, nested-lists

I need to create a memory game in Python. I need to print a 5x4 (4 rows, 5 elements in a line) field in the console and the fields should have names like a1, b1, c1... in the next row a2, b2, c2 etc. We've already got a list of symbols, which should be used in the game (list1). One of the instructions we have is to create nested lists here, which gives me a hard time. If you see below, I created a nested list, which shuffles the cards and puts them in a list. When I print those, I get the 5x4 row as needed.
If an user writes a1 and b2 in the console, I have to print the exact symbols that are placed in that row.

However, I have no idea how I should proceed at this point. I had some thoughts, but they seem to be unprofessional...

My idea:

- Create new list with fields a1, b1, etc. and print those. If an user writes a1 and b1, I get the index in the list and find the symbol at the same index in my cards list.
  --> Nested lists seem to be useless with that idea + creating a new list with fields is probably not wanted in that task

```
cards = ["✿", "❄", "★", "♥", "✉", "✂", "✖", "✈", "♫", "☀",
         "✿", "❄", "★", "♥", "✉", "✂", "✖", "✈", "♫", "☀"]
```

My solution so far:

```
def create_grid(cards):

    random.shuffle(cards)
    cards2 = [cards[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(cards), 5)]
    return cards2
```

Comment: Your `create_grid` function returns a 5x5 nested list, not a 5x4 nested list. Is that correct?

Comment: Hey Martijn, I am sorry for the confusion. Indeed the list created 4 rows and 5 elements in a row, this is actually what I needed. I think I wrote it wrong down.
This is the list I get from my code:
[['✂', '✈', '✖', '✈', '✉'], 
['☀', '♫', '♫', '♥', '★'], 
['✿', '✉', '♥', '✖', '❄'], 
['★', '☀', '❄', '✂', '✿']]

Comment: That's fine, just make sure you update your question to correct that reference. :-) So you have a nested list with 4 rows, and each row is a list with 5 columns. The columns are labeled with a, b, c, d and e, and the rows are numbered 1, 2, 3, and 4, correct?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using fields, translate the reference to two indices; one for the row, the other the column. Your nested list appears to use a list of *rows*, and each nested list is a list of cards at each column.  It *could* be that your nested list actually encodes columns and that each nested list holds cards at each row, but then you only have to swap the `row` and `col` variables in one place.

Once you have separate `row` and `col` variables you can then use those two values to index the nested list:

```
col, row = interpret_reference(reference)
card = grid[row][col]
```

where `reference` is the user's input. Note that `grid[row]` gives you the inner list of columns, and `grid[row][col]` then picks the right column.

Python lists are indexed with non-negative integers, so numbers from 0 and up.

So you need a way to translate the letter (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`) to an integer column index starting at 0, and the number (`1`, `2`, `3`, `4`) to an integer value *one lower*, so `"1"` becomes 0, etc., an operation  defined as a function named `interpret_reference()`.

There are lots of ways of doing that. One *simple* way would be to use a dictionary for both column letters and row numbers:

```
col_letters = {"a": 0, "b": 1, "c": 2, "d": 3, "e": 4}
row_numbers = {"1", 0, "2": 1, "3": 2, "4": 3}

def interpret_reference(userinput):
    col, row = userinput
    return col_letters[col], row_numbers[row]
```

Note that this returns `col, row`, the same order as the user input. In my first example code snippet, the variables are then used in the swapped order to index the nested list. **If your actual nested list structure is swapped**, simply swap the order to `grid[col][row]`.

The `interpret_reference()` function ignores error handling (where a user enters something that's not a valid reference). The function will raise an exception in that case, either `ValueError` when the input is not exactly 2 characters, or `KeyError` when they used a character that's not a valid row or column reference. See [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) for methods of handling user input with error handling.

There are, as mentioned, other techniques to map the user input to integer numbers.

- Computers encode text as numbers. What numbers exactly doesn't really matter, but you can rely on the numbers for lower-case ASCII letters (a, b, c, d, etc.) to be *consecutive*. The [`ord()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) gives you the integer number that the Unicode standard has assigned to a character, and if you then *subtract* the Unicode number (a *codepoint*) for the character `"a"` from that value you get an number starting at 0, provided you started with a lowercase letter:

  ```py
  col = ord(col_reference) - ord("a")
  ```

  This sets `col` to `0` if `col_reference` is the character `"a"`, `1`, if given `"b"`, etc.

  You could use the same trick for the number input, when entered on the keyboard in response to a `input()` call, Python receives the number part as a string. Subtract such ASCII digits (characters representing the Arabic numerals used in English) from `ord("1")` and you get the right row index.

- The [`int()` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) can take a string and interpret it as an integer number. Given the string `"1"`, it returns the integer value `1`. Subtract 1 and you are done:

  ```py
  row = int(row_reference) - 1
  ```

This changes how you handle errors, however; using dictionaries makes it easier to detect incorrect input because only *valid* input characters are keys in the dictionaries. When using `ord()` and `int()`, however, you also have to do extra work to validate that the resulting integers are not negative numbers and not too large (so larger than 3 or 4).

E.g. if the user gave you `z9` as input, you'd get `col = 25` and `row = 8` and then you'd get an `IndexError` when you tried to use those references. And `"99"` would also work as input, giving you `col = -40` because the ASCII character `"9"` comes *before* the lowercase letter `"a"` in the Unicode table (they have integer codepoint numbers 57 and 97, respectively).

Side note: your `create_grid` function **changes the `cards` list in-place**. It is probably fine, as long as your other code doesn't expect the card symbols to stay in their original order. You can replace `random.shuffle(cards)` with `shuffled = random.sample(cards, len(cards))` to get a *new* list that is shuffled without affecting the original `cards` list.

Answer (score 2):

As the names are fixed to `a1` to `d5`, you can use the ASCII code using `ord` for the first letter to get the row index.

```
import random

cards = ["✿", "❄", "★", "♥", "✉", "✂", "✖", "✈", "♫", "☀",
         "✿", "❄", "★", "♥", "✉", "✂", "✖", "✈", "♫", "☀"]


def create_grid(cards):
    shuffled_cards = cards.copy()
    random.shuffle(shuffled_cards)
    cards2 = [shuffled_cards[i:i + 5] for i in
              range(0, len(shuffled_cards), 5)]
    return cards2


grid = create_grid(cards)
print("Grid:")
for line in grid:
    print(" ".join(line))

print("")

while True:
    field = input("Enter a name of the field (0 to exit): ")
    if field[0] == '0':
        break
    field = field.lower()
    row = ord(field[0]) - ord('a')
    column = int(field[1]) - 1
    if row >= len(grid) or column >= len(grid[0]):
        print("The field is out of grid size. Try again.\n")
        continue
    print(f"{field}: {grid[row][column]}\n")
```

Output:

```
Grid:
✂ ✂ ❄ ☀ ✉
✿ ✖ ✈ ★ ♫
✖ ✉ ♥ ✿ ❄
♫ ★ ✈ ♥ ☀

Enter a name of the field (0 to exit): a2
a2: ✂

Enter a name of the field (0 to exit): b1
b1: ✿

Enter a name of the field (0 to exit): d4
d4: ♥

Enter a name of the field (0 to exit): e2
The field is out of grid size. Try again.

Enter a name of the field (0 to exit): 0
```

**Explanation:**

- I did not modify the original `cards` list. Rather I copied the content and shuffled them on the copy: `shuffled_cards = cards.copy()`
- The program takes field name from the user from range `a1` to `d4` and then print the value of that index from the grid.
- I parsed the input from the user and calculated the row and column. Row is calculated by using the ASCII code of the first character and column is calculated by subtracting 1 from the second character of user input as the list is 0 indexed.
- The grid has a size of 4 x 5. Thus, if user enters some large input, it will tell the user that the input field is our of the grid size.
- It takes field name from user until user enters `0`. You can change it as your need.